# Hive table loading: Unable to move source file

Tags: hive, bigdata

I begin learning BigData with Hadoop Hive

I can't upload local data to Hive table

Hive command is:
`load data local inpath '/usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt' into table nhanvien;`

I get error :

> Loading data to table hivetest.nhanvien Failed with exception Unable
>   to move source file:/usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt to destination
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/hivetest.db/nhanvi‌​en/testHive_copy_3.t‌​xt
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

was try:

```
hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse 

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/abc/employeedetails
```

it still get this error

can someone give me  solution ?

Comment: Can you post your load command and console error.

Comment: hive> load data local inpath '/usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt' into table nhanvien;
Loading data to table hivetest.nhanvien
Failed with exception Unable to move source file:/usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt to destination hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/hivetest.db/nhanvien/testHive_copy_3.txt
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

Comment: @SandeepSingh can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a permission issue. Try giving permission to local file and directory where your file exists.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt`

Then

Login as `$HDFS_USER` and run the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -chown -R $HIVE_USER:$HDFS_USER /user/hive
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 775 /user/hive
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 775 /user/hive/warehouse
```

You can also configure for `hdfs-site.xml` such as:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

This configure will disable permissions on HDFS. So, a regular user can do the operations on HDFS.

Hope this help.

Comment: can you provide output of `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hivetest.db/nhanvi‌​en`

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hivetest.db

drwxrwxr-x   - root supergroup          0 2017-05-18 17:23 /user/hive/warehouse/duongtest.db/nhanvien

Comment: but hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hivetest.db/nhanvi‌​en it say No such file or directory

Comment: now -rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup          0 2017-05-18 17:19 /user/hive/warehouse/duongtest.db/nhanvien/testHive.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup          0 2017-05-18 17:23 /user/hive/warehouse/duongtest.db/nhanvien/testHive_copy_1.txt

Comment: Its means user don't have permission to access directory.

Comment: can you tell me hdfs-site iton hadoop or hive because both have it

Comment: you need to change in `hdfs-site.xml` then restart hdfs and Hive

Comment: I also recommend to load data using `hdfs` user. If you are using `root` user then switch it to `hdfs` user.

Comment: what is hdfs user ? i need to create it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
hive -e "load data local inpath '/usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt' into table nhanvien;"
```

Comment: Can you show me:
hdfs dfs -ls -l /usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Where is /usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt?  If it isn't in local, you can try with:

load data inpath '/usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt' into table nhanvien;

Comment: i think it only ls -l /usr/local/nhanvien/testHive.txt

Comment: it will show -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 39 May 18 15:07 testHive.txt